# How to register Bootstrap menu in Wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Where I made a mistake? Nav menu in Wordpress looks different from HTML Bootstrap nav menu.

I used this and did not get the same result as in HTML document.

```
<?php 
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'theme_location' => 'primary',
    'container' => 'nav',
    'container_class' => 'navbar-collapse collapse',
    'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav'
));
?>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Products <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="steelandfire.html">Steel and fire doors</a></li>
                <li><a href="stainless.html">Stainless steel doors</a></li>
                <li><a href="acoustic.html">Acoustic doors</a></li>
                <li><a href="sliding.html">Sliding doors</a></li>
                <li><a href="revolving.html">Revolving doors</a></li>
                <li><a href="roller.html">Roller shutters</a></li>
                <li><a href="curtains.html">Fire curtains</a></li>
                <li><a href="gates.html">Gates</a></li>
                <li><a href="rapid.html">Rapid doors</a></li>
                <li><a href="access.html">Access control</a></li>
                <li><a href="accessories.html">Accessories</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Industry <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Medical</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Office and Residential</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Industrial</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Education</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Retail</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Shopping Mall</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Transportation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Warehouse and Logistics</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap nav walker functionality.
Download bootstrap nav walker file and upload  to your theme root directory.
https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker.

```
 <?php

                          wp_nav_menu( array(

                              'menu'              => 'primary',

                              'theme_location'    => 'primary',

                              'depth'             => 2,

                              'container'         => 'div',

                              'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',

                              'container_id'      => 'b3-navigation',

                              'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',

                              'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',

                              'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())

                          );

                      ?>
```

It's very easy to implement menu like bootstrap.
I Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You may apply the following code

```
wp_nav_menu(
   array(
   'menu' => 'main navigation',
   'container' => 'div',
   'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
   'container_id' => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
   'theme_location' => 'main navigation',
   'walker' => new WPSE_78121_Sublevel_Walker
       )
);
```

For the submenu you may need to apply the Wordpress walker class

```
class WPSE_78121_Sublevel_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul class='dropdown-menu'>\n";
}

function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
}

}
```

Hope it will helps you...